# Is there an alternate to "row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2)"?

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle's partition by. I see better I/O and less execution time. But I see CPU spike.
Is there an alter to partition by in the scenario provided below?
The SQL query:

```
SELECT C2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C2 ORDER BY C3) AS DISPLAY_ORDER 
  FROM MYTABLE;
```

Table Data:

```
C1, C2, C3
1, 1000, 101
2, 1000, 102
3, 1000, 200
4, 1000, 300
5, 1001, 100 
6, 1001, 101
7, 1001, 102
8, 1001, 103
```

Output:

```
C1, C2, C3
1, 1000, 1
2, 1000, 2
3, 1000, 3
4, 1000, 4
5, 1001, 1 
6, 1001, 2
7, 1001, 3
8, 1001, 4
```

Comment: I guess row_number() itself used the best possible algorithm to acheive this requirement. And analytic functions are supposed to consume more CPU.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why don't you want to use `row_number()`?

Comment: When I use PARTITION BY, I see CPU spike. That is the reason I do not want to use 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY'

Comment: You're trading off a (brief) higher CPU load for a shorter execution time (though you haven't said what you're comparing it with). Anything with less CPU would pretty much have to take longer. Without analytics you'd need to hit the table multiple times, or have overhead from your own implementation of an equivalent, e.g. via a PL/SQL collection or GTT. Is this really a problem, or are you overanalysing - what is often referred to as premature optimisation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DENSE_RANK` or `RANK` if it returns the same result on your data (on the sample you posted it does):

```
with t as 
(select 1 C1, 1000 C2, 101 C3 from dual
union all
select 2, 1000, 102 from dual
union all
select 3, 1000, 200 from dual
union all
select 4, 1000, 300 from dual
union all
select 5, 1001, 100 from dual
union all
select 6, 1001, 101 from dual
union all
select 7, 1001, 102 from dual
union all
select 8, 1001, 103 from dual)
select C1,
       C2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C2 ORDER BY C3) AS DISPLAY_ORDER1,
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY C2 ORDER BY C3) AS DISPLAY_ORDER2,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY C2 ORDER BY C3) AS DISPLAY_ORDER3
  from t;

    C1         C2     DISPLAY_ORDER1 DISPLAY_ORDER2 DISPLAY_ORDER3
---------- ---------- -------------- -------------- --------------
     1       1000              1              1              1
     2       1000              2              2              2
     3       1000              3              3              3
     4       1000              4              4              4
     5       1001              1              1              1
     6       1001              2              2              2
     7       1001              3              3              3
     8       1001              4              4              4
```

There is [forum thread](https://community.oracle.com/message/11159121) where stated that the performance is as follows: `dense_rank (fastest) > rank > row_number (slowest)`. But you would better compare the performance of all of them on your own data to decide.

Comment: Shabalin - I do not want to use 'PARTITION BY' since I see CPU spike with large volume of data. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: @Yaroslav: The forum thread link you provided CANNOT be trusted as no data experiments test results have been shown but just a final statement is declared. If there were any such comment on Oracle docs then that could be taken but not that link.

Comment: @nanosoft Performance depends on data set processed by query. I doubt that there could be any official confirmation in Oracle docs. As I stated you have to compare the performance of specific query on your own data to decide which one is better.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin - I understand and agree that performance need to be checked for each one's data. But precisely I just want to say the shared link doesn't add value and cann't be taken as confirmation. In answering here, I wouldn't add such links or like to see one as just a statement is given there without any test/reference of reliability.

Answer (score -1):

Using oracle analytic function is the most efficient approach. 
Thanks all for your input